# Make a Backbone collection of models with data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

i just got started with Backbone.js and think i've kinda understood the concept of it.

Backstory:
I made an interactive quiz with jQuery and Handlebars that i now want to migrate to Backbone.
The Quiz reads all the Questions from a static allQuestions.json file in the same directory.
The file looks like this:

```
{
"Q1" : {"question": "Vem är HON-chattens true Admin?",
"choices": ["Kattigpelika", "Bangan", "Naldor"],
"correctAnswer":0},

"Q2" : {"question":"Vem är chattens true mad son?",
"choices": ["Bangan","Grev3n","Mettapod"],
"correctAnswer":1
}
ETC...
```

(It's correctly formatted as i have used it before (with $.getJSON)

I am now trying to make a Model:

```
var Question = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize:function(){
    console.log("Created a model");
    }
);
```

that is part of the Collection:

```
var Questions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : Question,
url : "allQuestions.json"

});
```

I want the function:

```
allQuestions.fetch({
success:function(){
    console.log(allQuestions);
}
});
```

To create a new model for every object in the .json file and put it into the collection.
Is this possible? Where am I thinking wrong?

This is ALL done locally on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the "parse" function on your collection? http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Comment: Well done for your first outing (in both backbone & SO).  Sounds like this is all local (i.e. no web server).  Correct?  Is the issue getting the file to load or that when it loads it isn't parsing?

Comment: Yes it's all local. I will clarify that in my post.

The problem is that the whole .json file gets loaded into a single model within the collection. I want every object in my .json file to become an individual model in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not Backbone but the structure of your JSON object. If you can modify it to something like this, it would load different models for every question:

```
[
 {
  "id": "Q1", 
  "question": "Vem är HON-chattens true Admin?",
  "choices": ["Kattigpelika", "Bangan", "Naldor"],
  "correctAnswer":0 
 },
 {
  "id": "Q2", 
  "question":"Vem är chattens true mad son?",
  "choices": ["Bangan","Grev3n","Mettapod"],
  "correctAnswer":1
 }
]
```

You can check it working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/CJ5yx/6/).

Comment: Doesn't the formatting of JSON require everything to be objects?

I remember that the first version of the quiz had the questions in an array, but that wouldn't work when i moved the data to a .json file and used .getJSOn to retrieve it.

Comment: As I understand your problem every question it's an object and therefore a Backbone model while what you pass to the Backbone Collection it's an array of objects.

Comment: This actually solved the original problem i had. Thank you for the help as i would've never looked at the actual JSON-code myself.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you can put the data in the view that gets sent by the web server and load that (see http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap).

Otherwise, you need to redefine your collection's `sync` method so that if the method is "read" you call `$.getJSON` and otherwise you call `Backbone.sync` as usual.

Comment: It's all done locally, so no web server.

I'm looking into both the sync and parse methods of the collection and i think this is where i'll be able to solve my problem. Thank you. (Coming back to mark this one if i solve the problem.)

Comment: parse won't work: it gets called when you already have the data. But you could look into the code (https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction) to my book on Backbone Marionette (https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/) all of it is also done locally (without a web server, using local storage) see it in action here (on a web server, but it has no backend so it could be deployed locally just the same: try it by downloading the code on github): http://davidsulc.github.io/marionette-gentle-introduction

Comment: That first sentence about parse blew my mind, this kind of coding really takes another way of thinking. Your Marionette-git will absolutely solve my problems and is exactly what i was looking for.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It's pretty simple once you leran about it: `sync` interacts with the server, `parse` processes the data received, and `toJSON` prepares data for sending...